# Python 3 convert dictonary values to a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

so say that I have my dictionary

```
In [80]: dict_of_lists
Out[80]: 
{'Marxes': ['Groucho', 'Chico', 'Harpo'],
 'Pythons': ['Chapman', 'Cleese', 'Gilliam'],
 'Stooges': ['Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe']}
```

and I realise that later I will want treat the values as sets. How can I convert the dictionary from a values(lists) to a values(set) structure?

This is whati have tried.

```
In [84]: new_dict = [set(dict_of_lists.values()) for values in dict_of_lists.keys()]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-f49792cd81ac> in <module>()
----> 1 new_dict = [set(dict_of_lists.values()) for values in dict_of_lists.keys()]

<ipython-input-84-f49792cd81ac> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 new_dict = [set(dict_of_lists.values()) for values in dict_of_lists.keys()]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

and this pretty ugly effort.

```
In [83]: for list(dict_of_lists.keys()) in dict_of_lists:
   ....:     set list(dict
dict           dict_of_lists  
   ....:     set(list(dict_of_lists.values()))
   ....:     
  File "<ipython-input-83-08e0645abb2f>", line 1
    for list(dict_of_lists.keys()) in dict_of_lists:
       ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: Please show what kind of set you want to see as a result

Comment: You are actually creating a list of values as sets, not a dictionary. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = set(v)
```

---

To elaborate on why your attempts didn't work:

```
new_dict = [set(dict_of_lists.values()) for values in dict_of_lists.keys()]
```

In this line, you are:

- Iterating over the keys of the dictionary (good start, although you don't need to specify `.keys()` as that's the default for iteration over a dictionary);
- Assigning each key to the name `values` (confusing, if not necessarily terminal);
- Then, for each key in the dictionary, trying to convert all of the dictionary's values (which is a list of lists) to a set, which you can't do (lists are mutable and not hashable, so can't be a dictionary key or set element); and finally
- Trying to make a list, rather than a dictionary, from the results.

And then:

```
for list(dict_of_lists.keys()) in dict_of_lists:
```

Now you're iterating over the keys implicitly, which is good, but then trying to assign each key to the result of a call to `list`, with the explicit call to `keys` again; effectively, this line is:

```
['Marxes', 'Pythons', 'Stooges'] = 'Marxes'
```

which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> x
{'Pythons': ['Chapman', 'Cleese', 'Gilliam'], 'Marxes': ['Groucho', 'Chico', 'Harpo'], 'Stooges': ['Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe']}
>>> y = {k:set(v) for k,v in x.items()}
>>> y
{'Pythons': {'Gilliam', 'Chapman', 'Cleese'}, 'Marxes': {'Groucho', 'Chico', 'Harpo'}, 'Stooges': {'Curly', 'Moe', 'Larry'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_of_sets = {k:set(v) for k,v in dict_of_lists.items()}
```

This gives:

```
 {'Stooges': {'Curly', 'Larry', 'Moe'}, 'Pythons': {'Cleese', 'Chapman', 'Gilliam'}, 'Marxes': {'Groucho', 'Chico', 'Harpo'}}
```